# How to set value BOOL in Objective-C as same as Java in Firebase?

Tags: android, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

In Android, for changing the value for "status", we can set it as follows:

```
mDatabase.child("status").setValue(false);
```

If I set the values in iOS using @(FALSE)/@(YES), Firebase saves it as "status" = 0, which causes the Android application to crash:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to boolean

How can I set a true/false value in Objective-C?

Comment: Usually, it's objects that are sent, and we do it with a `NSNumber` for booleans: `@(FALSE)`/`@(YES)`?

Comment: If iPhone use @(FALSE)/@(YES), in firebase with status = 0

Android will be crashed
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to boolean
Android team don't like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @NO or @YES for setting boolean flags in Objective C